# Incrementing variable changes my pointer to pointer array values

Tags: c

Trying to create a table from a document formated as a table, but the value stored in the table changes after i++, why is that ?

```
int i, c, j=0;
int **vtab;

// C and L stands for columns ans lines

/* allocate memory for int value table   */
    vtab = (int **) malloc( L * sizeof( int *));
    for ( i=0; i<L; i++)
    {
        vtab[i]= (int *) malloc( C * sizeof( int ));
    }


do {
  c = (fgetc(fp) - 10); /* This function returns the character read as an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error. */
  if( feof(fp) ) {
     break ;
  }
  printf("%c", c);
  if (c != 32){
    if ( j>C ){
        j=0;
        i++;
    }
    vtab[i][j] = c;
    ++j;
  }
} while(1);
```

Comment: After your for loop, what is the value of `i`?

Answer (score 1):

`i` starts with an undefined random value, and therefore the behavior is *undefined*.

Note that `int i, j=0;` does *not* initialize `i` - it only initializes `j`.

Aside from that, `vtab` is declared a pointer to a pointer to an int, but it is never set to point anywhere, so it too points to a random memory address.